# How to split a string using comma?

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this

```
var assignments= "NAME1,NAME2,NAME3,NAME4,NAME5,NAME6"
```

how do i print only first three strings like this "NAME1,NAME2,NAME3" in JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

```js
let string= "NAME1,NAME2,NAME3,NAME4,NAME5,NAME6".split(',')
let output = string.splice(',',3).join(',')
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using standard `Array` functions you can do what you want. The code below shows the various stages, though you can write it more concisely as one line if you like.

```js
var assignments= "NAME1,NAME2,NAME3,NAME4,NAME5,NAME6"
var splitAssignements = assignments.split(",")
var firstThreeArray = splitAssignements.slice(0,3)
var firstThreeString = firstThreeArray.join(",")
console.log(firstThreeString)
```